# How to select random song to play (from the list) on a HTML5 site using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

My question is really easy, i am just a newbie in JavaScript and i need your help.
I want to create a site that will select random song, title of it and also its album from a list of sources. I want it to look something like this:

**Title:** (song 1 title here) 
**Album:** (album of song 1 here) 
(mp3 player here that uses the source of song 1)

I have HTML code for my player here:

```
<audio class="audio-element" controls="true" preload="none">

<!-- Adding audio sources -->

            <source src="mp3file.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
<br>
<b>Your outdated browser does not support HTML5. <br>
Get Mozilla Firefox <a href="https://www.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/new/"> >HERE< </a></b>

</audio>
```

No idea what to do next... Could you guys help? I would really appreciate explaining to me everything you do :) 
(Sorry for my bad english)

Comment: Do you want the random selection to be done in the browser by Javascript, or on the server when the page is being generated?

Comment: Next, you go look up Javascript tutorials, then come here when you have a specific question about your Javascript.

Comment: Well, damn, I did not expect being so downvoted :D I wanted it to be done in the browser, by Javascript :)

Comment: In what form is your list of songs?

Comment: I do not have any list, just songs (not many of them, maybe 40), so I can make any list is needed. I was thinking it would be possible to make list in Javascript (rolling a random number and then choosing from list of variables, f.e. mp3[0]=...\music\song1.mp3, title[0]="song 1", album [0]="album of song 1" etc. and then just put it all together using document.write, but my mp3 player doesn't seem to work in document.write) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot that goes into this, but here is a suggestion on how to start:

```
<b>Title</b>: <span id='songTitle'></span><br>
<b>Album</b>: <span id='songAlbum'></span><br>

<script>
var songs =
[
    { filename: "abc.mp3", title: "ABC", album: "Album1" },
    { filename: "def.mp3", title: "DEF", album: "Album2" },
    // and so on...
];

var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * songs.length);
var song = songs[randomIndex];
document.querySelector("source").src = song.filename;
document.getElementById("songTitle").textContent = song.title;
document.getElementById("songAlbum").textContent = song.album;
</script>
```

Comment: That's just what i wanted :) where do i put code for the mp3 player though? will it work if i just put it below? and also do i need JQuery on my page? thank you for your time anyways :)

Comment: Yes, putting the code at the bottom of the page will work (this is not actually good programming practice, but you have time to learn good practices later).  You don't need jQuery for this, though learning jQuery will make your life easier in many ways.

Comment: Hmm, something doesn't seem to work, i have blank spaces in Title and Album :(

Comment: Good opportunity to learn some debugging: add the statement console.log(song.title, song.album); right after var song = songs[randomIndex];  Open the Web Console in your browser, reload the page, and see what it prints.